# How do I print a certain index in a for-loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, indexing, printing

I have this code:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    print x[1],x[5]
```

Obviously it doesn't work so I wanted to know how to print a certain index in a for-loop without doing:

```
for x in range(1,10):
    if x == 1:
        print x
    if x == 5:
        print x
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use enumerate:

```
for i, v in enumerate(range(10)):
    if i == 5:
        print(i)
```

I prefer the above approach, as it is readable, and outputs it as you requested.

If you are really wanting to put this one line, you can do something like this, but, again, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the method above.

```
print(' '.join([str(i) for i, _ in enumerate(range(10)) if i in (1, 5)]))
```

Comment: anyway that uses only one line like `print x[index]`?

Comment: No and especially not with a print I believe. Also, not everything has to always fit on one line. Readability is very important.

Comment: yeah but I'm trying to make a grid with 1 to 9 numbers using a for-loop in it and a one line code would make it a lot nicer

Comment: You want the code to be understandable. And in many cases readability will be nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want to do with this, but here is an option

```
for idx,val in enumerate(range(1,10)):
    if idx in {1, 5}:
        print idx, val # print both the index and the value
```

Comment: thank you but I would like if it was only one line like `print x[index]`

Comment: You can't use a conditional in a one-line `print` statement AFAIK. And `x[index]` doesn't make sense because `x` is not indexable